# Getting error in service fabric "The application URL is not set or is not an HTTP/HTTPS URL so the browser will not be opened to the application"

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

When trying to run my service in service fabric cluster, the Output window says

> "The application URL is not set or is not an HTTP/HTTPS URL so the browser will not be opened to the application".

Am I missing a configuration step?

Answer (score 17):

You just need to enter a URL into the **Application URL** field.

To do so:

1. Click your Service Fabric Application project
2. In the **Properties** window, click **Application URL**
3. Specify a value, for **Debug** builds this will be http://localhost:19080/Explorer (the default for ASF Explorer)

[image]

Click **Debug.Start Debugging**; after a while the ASF Explorer will appear.

[image]

Comment: Once you have the explorer running you can check the endpoint for your service by expanding Applications (a software view of the cluster) and then going in depth for that particular service. For example for example if you have a service with UI and wan t to see it in the browser, copy the url from the endpoint ..

Comment: I'm having trouble viewing the screenshots, an https certificate warning.

Comment: @stealththeninja are you trying to view it across a network?  SF is designed to be viewed from within.   Try RDPing to the target machine then viewing via localhost

Answer (score 2):

It's a message from VS that in the project properties of the SF application, there's no 'Application URL' value specified. Nothing to worry about.

Setting this will launch a browser on that Url, when starting the debugger with F5.

Answer (score 0):

When the Output window says

```
The application URL is not set or is not an HTTP/HTTPS URL so the browser will not be opened to the application.
```

This is not an error. It's just telling you that it won't open a browser window automatically.

---

> ### You can see your application running in the browser by
>
> 1) Navigating to http://localhost:19080/ (if you haven't changed the port) or
>
> 2) Add the URL to the Project Properties
>
> - In Solution Explorer, right-click on the Project (Voting in this case) with the cluster icon to bring up the Property Pages.
>
> [image: Solution Explorer]
>
> - In Property Pages, add http://localhost:19080/ to the Application URL.
>
> [image: Property Pages]
>
> - Then restart your project.
> - Now the browser window will open automatically and you won't see `The application URL is not set...` in the Output window. You'll see `Launching the browser with URL http://localhost:19080/ to open the application.` in the Output window instead.